# Unable to make JSONP requests to Google Search webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jsonp

This is my fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/x06Lr919/4/**

```
$.getJSON('http://google.com/search?&q=hi&callback=?',
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#target").html(data.contents);

});
```

I would like to fetch the whole HTML of "`http://google.com/search&q=hi`"  as string of this webpage. I know of this website : [www.whateverorigin.org](http://www.whateverorigin.org) that lets me do it but I don't want to use any other external websites for this purposes.

I know, we have to use JSONP, and hence I've added the callback.

I'm unable to understand the type of data that is returned.  Tried `JSON.stringify` but wasn't helpful.

Comment: Error 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You can only use JSONP if the server you're fetching the data from supports it, and google's search results don't, it's not even JSON

Comment: Query String structure should look more like: `http://google.com/search?q=hi&callback=somecallback`.

Comment: Made the changes to prevent 404 error. @adeneo Is there any way around this? Like the file_get_contents(); in PHP?

Comment: @PHPglue callback function doesnt make a difference.I've tried it

Comment: Cross-Origin Request blocked.

Comment: PHP will get the content, no problem, but Google goes to great lengths to make sure you can't easily scrape their search results, so good luck trying to make that work. I do believe they offer a paid API for this sort of thing.

Comment: @adeneo In which case, how do you think "http://www.whateverorigin.org/" works? By making a server request each time?

Comment: You could use PHP's `DOMDocument`.

Comment: But is this client-side?

Comment: Use AJAX with `DOMDocument` then.

Comment: Hmm.I'm very doubtful if this would be client-side. Need some resource for an acceptable answer. Will have a look. Isn't there any other method?!

Answer (score 0):

You could scrape like this:

```
<?php
function searchGoogle($query, $pages = 1){
  $r = array();
  for($i=0,$n=0; $i<$pages; $i++,$n+=10){
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode($query)."&start=$n");
    $c = $doc->getElementsByTagName('cite');
    foreach($c as $e){
      if($e->hasAttribute('class') && $e->getAttribute('class') === '_Rm'){
        array_push($r, $e->nodeValue);
      }
    }
  }
  echo json_encode($r);
}
/* on your JavaScript page 
$.post('thisURL.php', {search:'Anything you want to search here.', pages:2}, function(urlsArray){
  // handle urlsArray here
});
*/
if(isset($_POST['search'], $_POST['pages'])){
  searchGoogle($_POST['search'], $_POST['pages']); // 20 results
}
?>
```

Comment: How do I verify that the google page is scrapped client-side and not server-side? If it is server-side then it beats my whole purpose.